# Web Request in mql5

Tags: mql5

```
#property copyright "2023, Kaweng Mancha"
#property link      "http://www.fostaa.com.ng"
#property version   "1.01"
#property strict
#property description "User Account Information Data Collection"

input string URL_create_account = "http://www.website.com/api/create_account.php";
input string URL_update_account = "http://www.website.com/api/update_account.php";
input string username = "user"; 
input string password = "password";

int OnInit() {
    EventSetTimer(1); // 1 minute timer
    return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason) {
    EventKillTimer();
}

void OnTick() {
    // Nothing to do on tick
}

void OnTimer() {
    string accountName = AccountInfoString(ACCOUNT_NAME);
    double accountBalance = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE);
    double accountEquity = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_EQUITY);

    string postDataStr = StringFormat(
        "username=%s&accountName=%s&accountBalance=%.2f&accountEquity=%.2f",
        username, accountName, accountBalance, accountEquity
    );

    // Convert string to char array
    char postData[];
    StringToCharArray(postDataStr, postData);

    // Define headers
    char postHeader[];
    string headerString = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    StringToCharArray(headerString, postHeader);

    int timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds timeout
    char result[], headers[];
    int res = WebRequest(
        "POST", // method
        URL_update_account, // URL
        postHeader, // headers
        timeout, // timeout
        postData, // data
        ArraySize(postData), // data size
        result, // response content
        headers // response headers
    );

    if (res == -1) {
        Print("WebRequest failed with error ", GetLastError());
    } else {
        Print("Server response: ", CharArrayToString(result));
    }
}
```

This code is expected to fetch user details on their mt5 accounts and send to my servrer which is already set up. But on this line:

```
int res = WebRequest(
        "POST", // method
        URL_update_account, // URL
        postHeader, // headers
        timeout, // timeout
        postData, // data
        ArraySize(postData), // data size
        result, // response content
        headers // response headers
    );
```

I get the error:
'WebRequest' - no one of the overloads can be applied to the function call
could be one of 2 function(s)

- built-in: int WebRequest(const string,const string,const string,const string,int,const char&[],int,char&[],string&)
- built-in: int WebRequest(const string,const string,const string,int,const char&[],char&[],string&)

Please help me out here